# Automate recreate list item with new date

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, conditional

Wondering if someone can provide some input on this -- I am a super-novice to Microsoft Flow so was not able to find a way to accomplish, but I believe this is technically feasible.

I have a SP (online) list that I would like to use to track annual site inspections.

[image]

The status column has 4 options (pending, completed, delayed, canceled).

Desire:
When a line item is changed to "completed" I would like to have a new item created, with a new due date (same month as completion date + 1 year), and status "pending".

This way the information, I never have to populated future review due dates. Everything is automated, and inspectors just need to modify list items.

Any help is appreciated! Descriptive help for a non-coder is adored!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should get you on the right track.  What you are looking for is the **`addDays expression.`**

```
adddays(items('Apply_to_each')?['DueDate'],366)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mohamed! The "value" option is not available in the "apply to each" step unless split-on is enabled. However, when enabled, the individual dynamic content fields are not available. I tried using "ID" instead of "value" but I get an error: The execution of template action 'Apply_to_each' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@triggerOutputs()?['body/{ID}']' is of type 'String'. The result must be a valid array.

Comment: Sorry, thanks @Taco_Buffet as well!

Comment: I got it to work -- I didn't use the apply to each and it was able to get it to work. thanks all!